# WPF DataGrid Property for Validation Error

Tags: c#, wpf, error-handling, datagrid, validationrules

I have three tabs, TabItem1, TabItem2 and TabItem3. In TabItem1, I have a DataGrid (MyDgr) in which the columns have been binded with ValidationRules.

The Validation Rules are working just fine and are catching entries with non-desired format (and even showing a red rectangle around the cell with issue). There is also a row tool tip that shows what error the Validation Rule caught.

The problem is that even though there is an error in the DataGrid, it is still possible to use another control, like clicking on TabItem2.

I would like to prevent the TabItems2 and 3 to be clicked (i.e. stay in TabItem1) if the DataGrid in TabItem1 still has errors.

Is there a property of the DataGrid that shows whether the DataGrid cells have errors (caught by the validation rules)? I was hoping to set a flag if the DataGrid shows an error that has not been fixed. Assuming the property to show that there is an unfixed cell error in the DataGrid exists and is called 'ErrorIsPresent', I would have something along these lines on TabItem2 and Tabitem3 click:

```
bool dgrHasAnError = MyDgr.ErrorIsPresent;
if(dgrHasAnError)
{ 
    TabItem1.IsSelected = true; //To 'forcefully' stay in TabItem1
}
```

I am not sure if there is a better way to achieve my goal. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you try disabling the other tab items when the selected one has an error?

Comment: @Ed thanks for your answer. It would be good to disable other TabItems. But the question is how to know that an error occurred in that particular DataGrid of TabItem1?
The Validation rules I am using in the DatagGrid in TabItem1, I am also using them in DataGrids of other TabItems as well.

That's why I was wondering whether there was a property of the DatagGrid that shows that a particular Validation rule has not been satisfied.